# PL/pgSQL: accessing fields of an element of an array of custom type

Tags: postgresql, variable-assignment, plpgsql

I've defined a custom type:

```
create type pg_temp.MYTYPE as (f1 int, f2 text);
```

Then, inside a function or a block, I've declared an array of such type:

```
declare ax MYTYPE[];
```

I can access an element through the familiar syntax `ax[1].f1`, but just for reading it.
When I use the same syntax for setting the field, I get a syntax error.

```
create type pg_temp.MYTYPE as (f1 int, f2 text);

do $$
declare x MYTYPE;
declare ax MYTYPE[];
declare f int;
begin

    x.f1 = 10;
    x.f2 = 'hello';

    --assigning an element: OK
    ax[1] = x;

    --reading an element's field: OK
    f = ax[1].f1;

    --writing an elememt's field: SYNTAX ERROR: 

    ax[1].f1 = f;

end; $$
```

The error is the following:

```
psql:test.sql:28: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 20:  ax[1].f1 = f;
          ^
```

I've tried also the syntax `(ax[1]).f1` with the same result.
Which is the correct syntax to do this?

Postgres server version: 9.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PLpgSQL is sometimes very simple, maybe too simple. The left part of assignment statement is a example - on the left can be variable, record field, or array field only. Any complex left part expression are not supported.

You need a auxiliary variable of array element type.

```
DECLARE aux MTYPE;

aux := ax[1];
aux.f := 100000;
ax[1] := aux;
```

Comment: Can you provide link to documentation where they say this? Here I couldn't find anything. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT - 8.3 doc is really obsolete

Comment: @PavelStehule: SQL `UPDATE` can do it. I wonder why it's not implemented in plpgsql? I added an answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Nobody wrote it. Original PLpgSQL was very simple interpret with basic functionality - without arrays, composites - lot of critical missing features was added - the SQL parsing and integration was totally redesigned and better left part is a feature without real significant value and interest from developer - PL/pgSQL is pretty static language with usually flat data types (relations). So there are not too much use cases where you miss this functionality and workaround is simple.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - maybe it is in ToDo, but I don't know anybody who would to work on this issue. It is waiting for motivated developer. PLpgSQL variables are independent on SQL engine - so routines from UPDATE implementation cannot be used (maybe with no trivial refactoring).

Answer (score 1):

That seems particularly inconsequent of plpgsql since SQL itself ***can*** very well update a field of a composite type inside an array.

Demo:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE mytype (f1 int, f2 text);

CREATE TEMP TABLE mycomp (c mytype);
INSERT INTO mycomp VALUES ('(10,hello)');

UPDATE mycomp
SET    c.f1 = 12     -- note: without parentheses
WHERE  (c).f1 = 10;  -- note: with parentheses

TABLE mycomp;
```

> ```
>      c
> ------------
>  (12,hello)
> ```

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE mycomparr (ca mytype[]);
INSERT INTO mycomparr VALUES ('{"(10,hello)"}');

UPDATE mycomparr
SET    ca[1].f1 = 12      -- works!
WHERE  (ca[1]).f1  = 10;

TABLE mycomparr;
```

> ```
>        ca
> ----------------
>  {"(12,hello)"}
> ```

I wonder why plpgsql does not implement the same?

Be that as it may, another possible workaround would be to use `UPDATE` on a temporary table:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   ax mytype[] := '{"(10,hello)"}';
BEGIN
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_ax ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT ax;

   UPDATE tmp_ax SET ax[1].f1 = 12;
   -- WHERE  (ax[1]).f1  = 10;  -- not necessary while only 1 row.

   SELECT t.ax INTO ax FROM tmp_ax t;  -- table-qualify column!

   RAISE NOTICE '%', ax;
END
$$;
```

That's more overhead than with [@Pavel's simpler workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41776317/939860). I would not use it for the simple case. But if you have lots of assignments it might still pay to use the temporary table.

Comment: The overhead is pretty significant in this case - temp table self is expensive due system tables updates, UPDATE is expensive due MVCC and storing data in pages - disc format (although it will not be stored in IO). Second cost is evaluating full SQL statement - not simple expression - so result can be 10-100x slower than my workaround - and it reason why native implementation cannot be based on current SQL functionality. You mentioned overhead - in this comment I am trying to explain this overhead.

Comment: Maybe implementation should not be too hard with short life auto variables - PLpgSQL can use my workaround implicitly. Good topic for some people who try to be PostgreSQL core developer :).

Comment: @PavelStehule: Maybe a [TODO item marked as "easier to implement"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Exotic_Features)?

Comment: @can be - but PostgreSQL ToDo means nothing :( it is black hole - a code is important