# How to modify a field in an array of records

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-11

I come from the Oracle world and try to migrate a package procedure.
Local types were declared in the Oracle package:

```
  TYPE t_class_record IS RECORD
  (
     id_class       classes.id_class%TYPE,
     field1         number,
     field2         number
  );

  TYPE t_classes_table IS TABLE OF t_class_record
     INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  l_classes_table                     t_classes_table;
```

`l_classes_table` is initialized by a SELECT statement where later single fields of single array elements are modified like this:

```
  l_classes_table(i).field1 := l_value;
```

So far I have done the following in PostgreSQL:

- Defined a composite type that corresponds to the structure listed above:

  ```
  CREATE TYPE t_class_record AS (id_class CHARACTER VARYING,
                                 field1   INTEGER,
                                 field2   INTEGER);
  ```
- Defined a procedure with a local variable of type Array of t_class_record:

  ```
  l_classes_array                   t_class_record [];
  ```

But when I try to modify a field of a record in the array I get a syntax error.

```
l_classes_array[i].field1 := l_value;
```

The error is `ERROR: syntax error at or near "." Position: 12414` where position points to the `.`after the `[i]`. I've no idea what's causing this syntax error.

My goal is to store an array of records in a variable so that I am able to modify individual fields of individual array elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Q/A has the reason and the solution to your problem:

[PL/pgSQL: accessing fields of an element of an array of custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772518/pl-pgsql-accessing-fields-of-an-element-of-an-array-of-custom-type)

Comment: Here is Tom Lane's take on that: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/30905.1562075577%40sss.pgh.pa.us